# Is this an efficient method of updating columns based on conditions in other columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is this an efficient method of updating columns based on conditions in other columns using pandas?
I am looking to generalize an update function that will move gaussian values and I had difficulty using lambda because there are multiple columns that could be conditions. Similarly apply was problematic because I couldn't get the variables to be in the form that it wanted, though honestly I probably could have spent more time on that part.

Problem statement:
How should I handle updating  large pandas dataFrames based on a value in another column in such a way that I could run many of these functions within acceptable speed parameters? Please respond with a complete example and if possible use my 'silly_series_generator' to make sure we are staying the same problem case. Thanks.

```
import random
import pandas


def silly_series_generator():
    # requires import of random and pandas
    ret = []
    ret.append(r.choice(['X', 'Y', 'Z']))
    for i in range(9):
        ret.append(random.gauss(0,1))
    return pandas.Series(ret, list("ABCDEFGHIJ"))


def silly_update(df, condition_col, condition_value, target_col, mean, sd = .1):
    # requires import of random and pandas
    effected_cells = df[condition_col] == condition_value[0]
    x = df[effected_cells][target_col] + r.gauss(mean, sd)
    df[target_col].update(x)
    return df


def run_test():
    # requires import of random and pandas
    # requires functions: silly_series_generator and silly_update
    rows = []
    for i in range(50):
        rows.append(silly_series_generator())
    original_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    print('original_df',original_df['B'].mean())
    updated_df = silly_update(original_df, 'A', 'X', 'B', 1)
    print('updated_df', updated_df['B'].mean())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_test()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the examples below are any faster (I'm sure the `apply()` is slower), but it's how I would do it.  Looking back on your problem - I'm not sure it's even different enough to write up, but here it is.

### Make the data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

def silly_series_generator():
    # requires import of random and pandas
    ret = []
    ret.append(random.choice(['X', 'Y', 'Z']))
    for i in range(9):
        ret.append(random.gauss(0,1))
    return pd.Series(ret, list("ABCDEFGHIJ"))

rows = []
for i in range(50):
    rows.append(silly_series_generator())
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

### Using apply

I think apply is typically the slowest route because it runs on one row at a time.  However I still like it so here's an example. We can provide the extra args to `apply()` with the kwargs.

```py
def update(row, condition_col, condition_value, target_col, mean, sd = .1):
    if row[condition_col] == condition_value:
        v = row[target_col] + random.gauss(mean, sd)
    else:
        v = row[target_col]
    return v

df['B'] = df.apply(update, axis=1, condition_col='A', condition_value='X', target_col='B', mean=1)
```

### Using a mask

This is basically what you did - I just used the `.loc[]` instead of `.update()`.  I'm not sure if it's any faster, but it's another option.

```py
mask = df['A'] == 'X'
df.loc[mask, 'B'] = df['B'] + random.gauss(1, 0.1)
```

### Using a mask - new random value for each row

It's unclear if you want the same random number added to each row.  The way we have it setup now, it's the same random number added to everything that matches.  It's likely we want each value shifted by a different random number each time.

Here's an example of making a new random number for each row. I'm leaving around some extra columns for debug.

```py
mask = df['A'] == 'X'
# Generate a random number for each row
# df['r'] = np.random.normal(1, 0.1, size=(df.shape[0],1))
# Only generate the random numbers for the mask locations
df.loc[mask, 'r'] = np.random.normal(1, 0.1, size=(df[mask].shape[0],1))
df.loc[mask, 'Bprime'] =  df['B'] + df['r']
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I wanted a different value for each row. It doesn't necessarily speak to the heart of the question but I wanted to give credit for recognizing that failing.